# .NET Core 3.1 Web Api byte array response truncated

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an API controller that returns a byte array, a CSV file, which gets truncated.
Is there any configuration settings that truncates the responses?

here is the code:

```
[HttpGet]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("ProcessedData")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileContentResult), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BusinessLogic.Dto.PagedProcessedData), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BusinessLogic.Dto.BadRequest), 400)]
public ActionResult GetProcessedData(int surveyID, int page = 1, string format = "json",
    DateTime? startDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null,
    string adm0Codes = null, int? marketID = null, string surveyType = null)
{
    try
    {

        byte[] file = Models.Repository.Survey.GetSurveyProcessedDataAsCSV(surveyID);
        if (file.Length == 0)
        {
            return BadRequest(new
            {
                Error = "No data available. Processed data becomes available after 24hrs from the upload. Please return after 24 hours."
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return File(file, "application/octet-stream", "MFI-ProcessedData.csv");
            // -> it returns a truncated file, always after 1,287,168 chars.
        }
    }
```

Comment: How big does the response get?  Is it MB or KB?  Is it a constant length?

Comment: @Neil It could be up to 4 ~ 6 MB and it's not constant length

Comment: How are you measuring the response?  Is it something like Postman or some other code you have written?

Comment: simply downloading the text file and opening it in notepad++

Comment: Are you sure Models.Repository.Survey.GetSurveyProcessedDataAsCSV(surveyID); returns the full file?

Comment: You might try something like this:
`var stream = File.OpenRead(path);
    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");` Don't forget to dispose the stream.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea Yes. it returns the full data.